# In RTL mode do icons need to be mirrored?

Tags: usability, website-design, icons, localization, rtl

I am working on a website that has both an English and Arabic version, and the site has a lot of icons. Can I flip all images in right to left direction for the Arabic version as shown below?

[image]

Comment: It seems like at least the "i" shouldn't have the letter part mirrored, even if the speech bubble is.

Comment: Mirroring that chart icon causes sales to go from good to bad

Comment: @Tyrsius : when user read from right to left the chart icon means bad to good i think.

Comment: Additional question: What about music player icons? I guess since they denote "directions", they must be mirrored, right? So, in arabic music player app, the 'previous track' button should point to the right and 'Play' button should point to the left. Is this correct?

Comment: @Pascal incorrect. Music player icons (and progress bar) should be kept the same as LTR. There are 2 reasons, one is that they denote the passage of tape from the beginning to the end (talking about old tape machines), which happened from left to right, and second, because all music electronics used to come from western countries (at least in the old times), so everyone is used to use them as in LTR.

Comment: Also, wanted to add that icons that don't denote the passage of time (like a magnifying glass for searching), shouldn't be mirrored since they represent physical objects and the majority of the population is right-handed, so even if they write RTL, the majority will pick up a magnifying glass with the right hand, so the handle still points to the right.

Comment: @AlejandroGarcíaIglesias Thanks a lot for this excellent explanation!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to consider an icon's usage and meaning to determine if it should be mirrored.

This [Google Material Design article](https://material.google.com/usability/bidirectionality.html#) gives a detailed description of icon mirroring.

> The main difference between left-to-right (LTR) and right-to-left (RTL) interfaces is how the passage of time is articulated. Languages that use LTR scripts depict time as passing from left to right, and languages that use RTL scripts depict time as passing from right to left.

What I assume is a download icon does not need to be mirrored because it does not display the passage of time.

[image: download icon]

The icon displaying a body of text needs to be mirrored to reflect the text-alignment of the script.

[image: icon with paragraph]

> Icons that contain representations of text need careful mirroring.  Text is right-aligned in RTL. If there is a paragraph indent at the beginning of a paragraph, an unfinished line at the end of the paragraph, or a ragged right side, the icons need to be mirrored.

The icons which display English script need to be mirrored and localized.

> Because *text in graphical elements will always require localization*, try to convey concepts in ways that don’t use text.

I think the speech balloon used for the below icons denote text-alignment so they should be mirrored. You should not mirror the English characters but instead replace them with Arabic script.

[image: help and information icons]

Comment: If you can avoid using Arabic-specific icons, then your icons will be usable in other right-to-left languages like Hebrew.

Comment: Hebrew uses the same question mark as English.

Comment: what about the question mark symbol? is it need to be mirrored?

Comment: In the case of the question mark and the i, the symbol wouldn't have to be mirrored, but I think the balloon _would_. So you'd have an attachment point on the right instead of on the left.

Comment: @krish For Arabic, yes - Arabic uses a question mark that appears similar to the English one but opens the opposite way. For Hebrew, no - Hebrew uses the same question mark as English. Greek, incidentally, is written from left to right but uses a question mark that looks like an English semicolon. These issues are more complicated than just flipping things around. The letter "i" [I assume for "information"] may or may not be familiar and meaningful to audiences that speak various other languages.

Comment: I guess the download icon also doesn't need to be mirrored because it's symmetrical about its vertical axis...

Comment: "how the passage of time is articulated" : This means that an Arabic Music player app should have its Play/previous/next/rewind/fast_forward buttons mirrored then? Or not..?

Comment: the chart x and y axis have nothing to do with writing directions, even in Arabic the chart (0,0) point is left most. so no, the chart mirroring will NOT have the same meaning to RTL viewers, it will mean "good to bad"

Answer (score 9):

RTL (right-to-left) indicates a different text direction, but not a mirror image of the same content in LTR (left-to-right). Mirroring the Latin letter *R* roughly gets you the Cyrillic letter *Я*, which is the (horizontal) mirror image visually speaking, but does **not** by any means indicate a change in text direction. Similarly, images cannot be simply mirrored horizontally either.

To use your pictograms as examples, the text balloon should be mirrored, because otherwise the protrusion would point the wrong way in the text flow, and therefore the flow of time as explained by Andre Dickson's citation. Mirroring the graph, however, requires more careful thought; how are graphs read in RTL languages? If they are read the exact same way as in LTR languages, mirroring the graph changes its meaning from increasing to decreasing values on the Y-axis. Multilingual support is a specialty that requires its own research, and you may find it beneficial to collaborate with native speakers of the languages you are working on supporting.

Comment: Good point about the graph

Comment: if so i need to check with native Arabic users

Comment: +1 for "collaborate with native speakers".  Having said that, well-designed icons are usually language neutral.  I'm sure that a native Arabic speaker would understand an English-style question mark, even though an Arabic question mark resembles its mirror image.  Most of your icons shouldn't need to change at all - those that do will probably need something other than a straight mirror-flip.