# Do airplane icons need to be mirrored for RTL languages?

Tags: internationalisation, rtl

If our product uses an airplane icon like this one, do we mirror it for our RTL UI?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In RTL mode do icons need to be mirrored?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/100162/in-rtl-mode-do-icons-need-to-be-mirrored)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with direction (left / right), so no need to mirror it.